# hudson subversion plugin

Tags: svn, hudson, hudson-plugins

is there a way to force Subversion Plugin to ask authentication to an SVN repository every time users launch a job ?

In detail: we have a job that perform a checkout from an SVN branch and then deploy the .ear checked-out. 
The Subversion Plugin need authentication details (user & pwd) on the job configuration, while we would like that a user type his credentials when he launch the job.

Is this possible? There is some workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a "build" that does this in Hudson, you should probably then [configure the build to be parameterized](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build).

You might need to augment this with the use of scripts to actually run the svn / deployment commands outside of the integrated Hudson tasks, as the Hudson tasks will typically take any "known" Hudson credentials (or even credential cache) and use those as parameters in the plugin.

Note that this might have the undesired side-effect of exposing the user's password in the log files, as Hudson won't know that this parameter should be handled "specially" in the logging.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply (I'm a little late in reading the answers)!

I have already used username and password parameters in an Hudson job that runs a wsadmin command on a remote WAS and in that case the solution was perfect.

In the case of Subversion Plugin, the solution you propose seems to me a bit complex to implement. 
For now the solution I have implemented is to use a "service user" mapped on SVN and associated exclusively to Hudson. Each SVN activity performed by Hudson (tagging, checkout, ..) will be made ​​with this user.

Anyway, thanks for your solution!